# Website doesn't work with both Edge and E11: "The connection to the website was reset"

Tags: connection, website, internet-explorer, reset

[Our website](https://codecave.pro/) works on all non-Microsoft browsers, such as FireFox, Safari, Chrome, Android Browser 5.0/6.0 etc

The error message is the following:

```
The connection to the website was reset.

Error Code: INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE
```

on the screenshot:

[image: The connection to the website was reset]

**UPDATE**:

We haven't tested this error on version of Windows lower than Windows 10 Anniversary and Creators Update.

Comment: Can you provide a packet capture of an attempt to access the site from a clean install which never accessed the site before?

Comment: You should copy the error message into the question such that searching and copy-paste will work.

Comment: @kasperd added error messages

Comment: As much as I cringed to "click" the link, I just hit it fine on IE 11 under Win 7

Comment: @Colt we don't have such old Microsoft installations. I've updated the question by adding the information on Windows versions we used for tests (Windows 10 Anniversary / Creators Update both Pro and Standard editiobs)

Comment: Can you show a packet capture of what is being exchanged? The error message sounds as if the server close the connection while the client is busy sending something to the server. It would be nice to get that confirmed and also to know what exactly the client is sending at that point. From the error message I can't really tell if it happens already during client hello or as late as when the request body is being sent.

Comment: @kasperd Wireshark is a free tool and codecave.pro website has always been a public resource, so there is no need to do the capturing on my side, literally anyone (who has an Internet connection) could do it.
Anyway I've found out what was the problem and posted an answer, hopefully it will help other people and I'm sure it will, because it has been viewed 2500+ times

Comment: Sorry not an answer --but you could delete this ...@ Salaros Can you visit this link: https://serverfault.com/questions/911224/differnce-between-non-microsoft-and-microsoft-browsers-with-regards-to-tls-hands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally managed to fix this nasty issue! Basically it was all about `X-Content-Security-Policy` header being multi-line in my NGINX config.

So I just flattened this snippet:

```
add_header X-Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; \
 script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; \
 img-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com";
```

into this ugly one-liner:

```
add_header X-Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; img-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com";
```

Now IE and Edge work, yay!

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same Error with IE & Edge on Windows 10 (Windows 7 was fine)

In my case the cookies were to big, about 6~7kb. If I resized the cookies to < 1kb it worked also for this browser.